# Filtering anchors in list

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list that I am representing as a tree and toggling the nodes when they are clicked

```
$('#tv').find('.child1, .child2').click(function () {
       $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(1000);
       return false;
});
```

How do I filter links from toggling? i.e if any of the Li's has any link in it, clicking on that link should not trigger toggle

Answer (score 1):

stop the event propagation from the `anchor` element within the `li`

```
$('#tv').find('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

another solution is to filter it in the click handler

```
$('#tv').find('.child1, .child2').click(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('a').length == 0){
       $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(1000);
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: not sure if that's the best way. I want to be able to do it as a filter in my existing code without affecting performance